# Including PHP Defines() using Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, autoloader

I'm using Composer for module dependency management (loving using autoload.php instead of a ton of includes and requires!).

I want to include a PHP file that is outside of the root Composer directory (for security) with credentials stored in `defines()`.

This isn't working, **composer.json**:

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": ["../credentials.php"]
  }
}
```

**credentials.php**:

```
define('RYAN','BRODIE');
```

**test.php**:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
echo RYAN;
```

Results in `Notice: Use of undefined constant RYAN`. If Composer's autoloader is only intended for Class includes then I'd be grateful for any hacks (as it were) to make this work.

Comment: Using class constants rather than global constants would be one option

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That method should work fine, however you'll need to use `files` instead of `classmap` for example;

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "../constants.php" ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome worked a treat, will accept when I can, thanks Tom :) Not sure how I missed this in the docs