# How to use constant defined in another file?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Let’s say I have two files:

App/Version.php

```
<?php

namespace App;
const VERSION = "0.1.0";
```

App/Http/Controllers/AppController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use const App\VERSION;

class AppController extends Controller
{
    public function version()
    {
        return VERSION;
    }
}
```

With this, I’ve got "Undefined constant 'App\VERSION'" when I call `AppController@version` route.

I use composer. Probably, the question is about how to autoload constant...

Comment: Do you use composer for autoloading or you just require the file?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek , Composer.

Answer (score 2):

As composer is using, file with constants can be added to autoload as shown in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17404435/4332851

Answer (score 1):

You can have a third file, which is included in those 2. Usually such file is called config.php or init.php

Comment: I use composer. I don't use `require`.