# PHP referencing constant in a namespace not working "Undefined constant"

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces, constants

I've searched a lot of other similar Q/As but none of them seem to address this specific case:

There's a file with constants:
`App/Core/SomeConstants.php` which contains:

```
namespace App\Core\SomeConstants;
const MY_CONST = 'myconstvalue';
```

Then there's a controller using this constant like so:

```
use const App\Core\SomeConstants\MY_CONST;
something("foo" . MY_CONST);
```

According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php this I thought would work, but doesn't and when I run that usage code (of course after reloading the autoloader/clearing cache), I get `Undefined constant \"App\\Core\\SomeConstants\\MY_CONST\""`.

I even tried full-namespace referencing like `something("foo" . \App\Core\SomeConstants\MY_CONST);` and still nothing.

What's also interesting is that IDE vscode doesn't have an issue with it and actually shows proper hinting and stuff in both of the cases.

What am I doing wrong? Can it even be done **without** wrapping the constant into a class? Where is this behavior documented? Thanks

Comment: I tested your example and it works. Constant defined in one namespace and used in other, same as in your post. That said - I would still consider putting it into some class.

Comment: You are missing the `require` directive. AFAIK, composer won't autoload them automatically. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17404351/#17404435) for the required configuration.

Comment: @msg that is very sad, but using the ` "files"` section in `autoload` section of `composer.json` worked, so at least there's a bypass :-) thank you

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @msg in a comment, the `require` directive is missing. It's necessary to load the PHP file containing the defined constant.

```
// file1.php
namespace Ns1;
const MYCONST = "some value";

// file2.php    
namespace Ns2;
require "path/to/file/containing/myconst.php";
$val = Ns1\MYCONST;
```